# Will Forefront 2010 Antispam/Antivirus protection work on all-in-one Exchange 2010 servers in DAG

Tags: exchange-2010, microsoft-forefront-2010, dag

We have 2 `Exchange 2010` servers with every single role on each. Servers are in DAG mode and they have `TMG 2010` as entry point and doing as `load balancer`. Can I install Forefront 2010 on both Exchange servers and have `Anti spam` protection? I read somewhere that Edge is preferred for this kind of things but we don't have an edge server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Exchange Edge Transport role and Forefront Protection for Exchange 2010 will integrate neatly with TMG if you wanted to do it that way.

Otherwise, FPE2010 can also be installed on hub servers. Some [features](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/forefrontexchange/thread/5f21cfff-a68c-4248-aba6-bdadae3a3312) won't be available though.

Edit: Sorry, I missed the DAG part! See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bestpracticesforconfiguringforefrontprotectionforexchange.aspx) (bottom of the page) for considerations on DAG servers.